# CSS Help - Mobile footer menu blocked by content

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

I could really use some help please. I am working on a mobile version of http://www.lifelineconnections.org/.

1) When it is adjusted for mobile the text box at the bottom (.insurance .col-right) covers the footer blocking a menu.

2) In my search for assistance, I was told "There is a typo in the header, with including the bootstrap-theme.min.css. There is a period before the http. :

```
    <link href=".http://www.lifelineconnections.org/wp-content/themes/wplifeline/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This theme uses bootstrap which I'm not familiar with yet and I cannot find the location of this typo. I've searched header.php and most of the rest. and looked throughout the plugins. I do not think this is causing the footer issue but may be causing a problem with Googlebot search errors this site has been receiving. I just took on this site and it needs some work.

I'm also new to stackoverflow so if files or images are needed please say something.

thanks.

Comment: I don't believe that is your issue, It seems more likely to be an extra closing div tag somewhere around the `<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div></form></div>` line of code, possible the `</div>` at the end of the line I just pasted. This will cause the problem you are seeing.

Comment: do you know any tips for searching.... other than opening each file and using chrome's find feature?

Comment: [opinion] I use Firefox and notepad++ with winscp for FTP connection, I often have all files open relative to the work I'm doing that save directly to the server. I use the find feature in notepad++ or in Firefox's Firebug (f12) and look at the code there, or view the source if I don't have access.

Comment: Sadly we cannot be discussing such suggestions on stack-exchange sites. My opinion would open up the need for other opinions and never result in a 'best' solution, and this is not really your problem in hand. Also make sure you are in the wordpress theme files, to edit the theme html.
When inspecting your code have a look for `</div> <!-- /container -->` it's just before here that your code breaks. Your wordpress installation could also be compromised. and malicious code may be breaking some of the function. That's very common.

Comment: Removing exactly this segment of code http://pastebin.com/DDjRq48N fixes the formatting errors. Finding it is up to someone with access. Sorry :)

Comment: thanks, I deleted the inappropriate question. your help is much appreciated. :)

Comment: I'm not seeing any extra div's on the original index.php file. do you think it may be a css class issue after all?

Comment: header.php, index.php, footer.php it may also be included via a plugin.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "the code breaks" just before <!--/container --> I'm building the page in codepen to try to get the whole picture. and play with the css if I can put all the pieces together..... Would you happen to know where to find the html for <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'footer-menu' ) ); ?> It's not in footer.php ---that's where I found this.